# You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am trying to create an activity with a button that runs color picker for my app,
here is my **Activity** code :

```
public class color extends AppCompatActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_color);
        final ImageView imgbck= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        ImageButton imgbt= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.colorpickerbt);
        imgbt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ColorPickerDialogBuilder
    .with(getApplicationContext())
    .setTitle("Choose color")
    .wheelType(ColorPickerView.WHEEL_TYPE.FLOWER)
    .density(12)
    .setOnColorSelectedListener(new OnColorSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onColorSelected(int selectedColor) {
            String ss=Integer.toHexString(selectedColor);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ss,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    })
    .setPositiveButton("ok", new ColorPickerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int selectedColor, Integer[] allColors) {
            imgbck.setBackgroundColor(selectedColor);
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        }
    })
    .build()
    .show();
            }
        });

    }
```

everything is working fine but when i hit the button i get this error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.soheil.prolightfa, PID: 31576
java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:310)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:279)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:253)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialog.setContentView(AppCompatDialog.java:76)
at android.support.v7.app.AlertController.installContent(AlertController.java:213)
```

im also adding my styles:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

and Style v14

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>
```

and v11

```
  <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>
```

and i also changed the activity to Appcompactactivity
what should i do ?

Comment: Refer :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: Change Activity to AppCompatActivity. Just to add, read about Java naming conventions for classes.

Comment: Could you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to your styles and put the parent

```
parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
```

instead of

```
parent="Theme.AppCompat"
```

Or you can use `AppCompat` for backward compatibility.

Comment: i have 3 style.xml ,v11, and v14 which one ?

Comment: values-v11 : Version is 11 or higher and values-v14 : Version is 14 or higher. Style.xml is the default folder and it will be the last to be matched, covering other APIs levels not covered by another values-xx folder.

Comment: You are getting this exception because you are not using AppCompat. You can add appcompat dependencies, to your project will also solve the problem. You can not use AppCompat right now. Change it to as mention in answer

Answer (score 1):

### Your logcat throwing

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

- At First extends `AppCompatActivity` instead of `Activity`

> public class color extends AppCompatActivity {

You can share your Application style.

1. First section `parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">`
2. another section `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">` in `v11`

[You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity)

Comment: add `parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">` in `v14`

Comment: added android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar in V14 activity starts but when i press button same problem ocuur, and added android:Theme.Holo.Light in style.xml activity wont start and same error occurs

Comment: @SoheilAfshari Its better to set `parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` in `Application theme`

Comment: And class name first name must be Capital `Color` . not `color`

Comment: And also make sure using AppCompat dependencies

Comment: ColorPickerDialogBuilder is part of a GitHub repository that i used before could this be a problem ? https://github.com/QuadFlask/colorpicker